# Printing psobject values in single line in powershell

Tags: powershell, file-writing

I am generating multiple PSObject's in a loop and storing all those in an other  output object. And writing that into a file as below.

```
$output = ForEach ($r in $results){
          New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
          A  = $X
          B = $Y 
          C = $Z          
         }   }
$output | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize *| Out-File -Append $File
```

I wanted to know how to fit the value of one object in single line. The above line works in client machine and when I run on server it fails.
I am Ok, if it is a CVS format also.

Comment: `$output | Export-CSv $File -NotypeInformation`

Comment: Its a very large collection so, Export out side the loop has memory issues and to keep Export inside loop, it doesn't support append.

Comment: Export-CSV does support append. If yours does not, your install of powershell is corrupt.